# Random variable question from Introduction to Algorithms C3.9

Tags: probability, random-variables

In CLRS Introduction to Algorithms 3ed, on Page 1201, C3.9 there's the following question:

> Show that for any random variable $X$ that takes on only the values
>   $0$ and $1$, we have $Var[X] = E[X] \cdot E[1-X]$.

Here's the Answer:

> Since $X$ only takes the values $0$ and $1$, we will always have that
>   $X^2 = X$. Then, the probability that $X$ takes the value of $1$ is
>   equal to the expected value of $X$. So, \begin{align}Var[X] &= E[X^2] − (E[X])^2
> \\&= E[X] − (E[X])^2
> \\&= E[X](1 − E[X])
> \\& = E[X](E[1] − E[X])
> \\&= E[X](E[1 − X]) \end{align}

What I don't understand is why "the probability that $X$ takes the value of $1$ is equal to the expected value of $X$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ with probability } p \\ 0 &\text{ with probability } 1-p \end{cases}$$

Hence $$\mathbb{E}[X]=p(1)+(1-p)(0)=p$$

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$E(X)=\sum xP(X=x)=1\cdot P(X=1)+0\cdot P(X=0)=P(X=1).$$
$$E(X^2)=\sum x^2P(X=x^2)=1^2P(X=1^2)+0^2P(X=0^2)=P(X=1).$$